# Keep apt install from autoremoving packages?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ros

I'm currently running Ubuntu 16.04, and have ros-kinetic-desktop-full installed. I also need to install python3-rospkg. However, when I try to install this, it autoremoves all extra packages installed by the kinetic installation.

How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try marking "on hold" the package(s) you do not want to be removed:

```
sudo apt-mark hold ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Then install `python3-rospkg`.